# ggplot K-Means Cluster Centers and Clusters

Tags: r, ggplot2, k-means

I'm working on a K-Means Cluster `ggplot()`, and can almost do what I'm hoping to but I just can't figure out how to color my centers the same colors as their respective clusters.

So far I have this:

```
data(mtcars)
library(ggplot2)
c1 <- kmeans(mtcars,9)
x <- tapply(mtcars$mpg,c1$cluster,mean)
y <- tapply(mtcars$hp,c1$cluster,mean)
kcenters <- data.frame(x,y)
ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,hp))+geom_point(col=c1$cluster,size=4) +  geom_point(data=kcenters,aes(x,y),pch=8,size=10)
```

Which gives me this plot:[image]

So I have two questions, how can I color my centers the same as the cluster they are representing? Also, I feel as though the `x` and `y` code is extra that doesn't need to be there because in my `c1` values I can see centers with the matrix of location and the color they represent as well. I just haven't been able to figure out how to write the code to access this part as every time I try I get an error such as...

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): shape, colour, size
```

The other, less important question is about why I have two different black clusters. Doesn't R have more than 8 unique colors it can call on by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You can use

```
 ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,hp))+geom_point(col=c1$cluster,size=4) +  
     geom_point(data=kcenters,aes(x,y),pch=8,size=10,colour=1:9)
```

To generate more colours you should look at `rgb(...)`
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you merge together relevant data into data.frames before using ggplot. Then you can use the build in color options. Here's an example

```
ggplot(cbind(mtcars, cluster=factor(c1$cluster)))+
    geom_point(aes(mpg,hp, col=cluster),size=4) +
    geom_point(data=cbind(kcenters, cluster=factor(1:nrow(kcenters))),aes(x,y, col=cluster),pch=8,size=10)
```

This produces

[image]